# Time in Space (1 year in space, 7 years on earth?)

Tags: time, spacetime

I heard that in certain parts in space, time will move faster than on earth.

So they say 1 hour is 7 years on Earth.

So what I would like to ask is if you have 1 hour in space, would you age the same as on earth. So if you arrived back on earth would you be younger than people in your family?? How does this work I don't understand.

Comment: I don't believe it."I heard that X, so if X is true..." questions are not likely to get answers because they are based on unverifiable premises. Also, questions about basic physics are not on-topic here. [Twin paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox) questions are on-topic in [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com) and my guess is that this one will already be answered there.

Comment: It sounds like you have basic questions on Relativity. Why don't you start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_relativity

Comment: This has nothing to do with space, but everything with velocity and general relativity. If you manage to go fast on earth, the same thing happens. Suffice to say, we can not actually reach any appreciable fraction of speed of light, so this is not a *practical* problem we face with spaceflight (yet).

Comment: This sounds like backstory for the planet with insane time dilation from being at a tiny distance from the event horizon of a supermassive black hole the sci-fi movie _ Interstellar_.